# URL linking in django is getting failed

Tags: django

Error in line 13, the system shows. It is in Home page of blog project.

```
<h1>Posts</h1>
<ul>
    {% for post in object_list %}
    <li>
        <a href=" {% url 'article-detail' post.pk %} "> {{ post.title }} </a>
        {{ post.author.last_name }} {{ post.author.first_name }}
        <br /><br />
    </li>
    {{ post.body }}
    <br /><br />
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

In views.py

```
class AddPostView(CreateView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'add_post.html'
    fields = '__all__'
```

and in urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', HomeView.as_view(), name='home' ),
    path('article/<int:pk>/{% post.title %}', ArticleDetailView.as_view(), name='article-detail'),
    path('add_post/', AddPostView.as_view(), name='add_post')]
```

Can any one help me please?

Comment: [edit] your question and provide error in text format.

Comment: What is this `{% post.title %}` supposed to do?

Comment: {% post.title%} to display the title of the post on home page.

Comment: Thank you both Ankit and Willem Van Onsem, Your response ever help learners like me.